# HDP Ambari installation in Ubuntu12.04

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

What are the steps to install HDP 2.0 through Ambari? I have tried with the steps described in the Hortonworks documentation. But, the installation is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Ambari supports RHEL (centos) 6 and 7 ; SLES 11sp3 ; Ubuntu 12 and Ubuntu 14 ; Debian 7.

Comment: Thanks. But in HortonWorks website they said that the HDP 2.0[Ambari installation] is available for Ubuntu too [in here](http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp-2/)